# Sonata admin: Display entity grandchildren in sonata_type_collection

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

I have the following entities:

```
// AppBundle/Entity/Contacts.php

/**
 * @var Collection
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Nominations", mappedBy="contact")
 **/
private $nominations;


// AppBundle/Entity/Nominations.php

/**
 * @var Contacts
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Contacts", inversedBy="nominations")
 **/
private $contact;

/**
 * @var Votes
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Votes", mappedBy="nomination")
 **/
private $votes;


// AppBundle/Entity/Votes.php

/**
 * @var Nominations
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Nominations", inversedBy="votes")
 **/
private $nomination;
```

With the following method in the Contacts entity, which loops through the Nomination records and stuffs them in an ArrayCollection that I want to display in ContactsAdmin:

```
// AppBundle/Entity/Contacts.php

/**
 * Get Votes
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 */
public function getVotes()
{
    $return = array();

    foreach ($this->getNominations() as $nom) {
        $return = array_merge($return, $nom->getVotes()->toArray());
    }

    return new ArrayCollection($return);
}


// AppBundle/Admin/ContactsAdmin.php

$formMapper
    ->add('votes', 'sonata_type_collection', array(
        'required' => false,
        'by_reference' => false
    ), array(
        'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Votes',
        'admin_code' => 'app.admin.votes', //this is a VotesAdmin service which works fine on its own
        'edit' => 'inline',
        'inline' => 'table',
    ));
```

But I'm getting this error:

> The current field `votes` is not linked to an admin. Please create one for the target entity : ``

Note the entity name there is blank. I've tried all sorts of different combinations of options but I keep coming back to this same problem: Sonata can't figure out what the entity class and related admin is, even though I'm specifying it.

Comment: Can you show us your use statements in the Contacts class? Is the namespace for the Votes class correctly imported?

Comment: All Entities are in the same namespace \AppBundle\Entity

Comment: Without specifying the admin_code or if you remove your custom code in the getVotes, do you have the same issue ?

Comment: If I remove admin_code I get the same error. I'm not sure what you mean by remove my custom code from getVotes? The entire function is custom written, not generated, since there is no Votes association or property in my Contacts entity. But yes, if I remove it I still get the exact same error.